# Selecting first div usin jquery

Tags: jquery, html, selection

How we can select first div of page using jquery ?

Comment: `$('div:first')` http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery first select:
http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

> The :first pseudo-class is equivalent to :eq(0). It could also be
>   written as :lt(1). While this matches only a single element,
>   :first-child can match more than one: One for each parent.

Sample:

```
var div = $('div:first');
```

Fiddler example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wBQfm/

Comment: var div = $('div').filter(":first"); actually achieves the best performance, since  queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method.

Answer (score 2):

Get the first using this:

```
var first_div = $( $('div')[0] );
```