# How to return first <div> of first <a> relative to an element selected by ID?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have this sort of structure:

```
<div id ="anid">
    <div>
         <div>
               <a>
                   <div class ="someclass"></div>
               </a>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is known in advance that the structure is so.

I also know there are other divs with class "someclass" but they are ones I need to avoid.

Should I be doing something like:

```
what_I_need = $('#' + anid + ' a:first ' + ' div ');
```

Or if I have option to alter the code, should I just give the div I am looking for an ID? This particular bit of code will not be run often. It isn't something that has to be super optimized. That said, lately I am trying to understand what sorts of DOM traversals are costly and what tips are there to reduce traversal time. But that would be separate topic...

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can remove quote and get the first. You can use [0] too. please see
 :[Selecting first div usin jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316869/selecting-first-div-usin-jquery)

```js
anid = "anid"
alert($('#' + anid + ' a:first div').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="anid">
    <div>
         <div>
               <a>
                   <div class ="someclass">test</div>
                   <div class ="someclass">test2</div>
               </a>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this answer help you, please validate this. Thanks @Brian